# Package Installation Error - Install Version Null Reference Exception

Tags: packages

I created a Sitecore Package. I tested the package in a test environment and it worked fine. But, in the client's environment, one of the items in the package fails with this error:

```
ManagedPoolThread #14 08:04:33 ERROR Error installing items/master/sitecore/templates/User Defined/Pages/Contact Us Form Page/{13B87AC4-38BD-43C6-A5D7-FCB1D081533F}/en/1/xml 
Exception: System.NullReferenceException 
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Source: Sitecore.Kernel 
at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.VersionInstaller.InstallVersion(Item version) 
at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.VersionInstaller.PasteVersion(XmlNode versionXml, Item target, VersionInstallMode mode, IProcessingContext context, Boolean removeOtherVersions) 
at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry) 

ManagedPoolThread #14 08:04:46 ERROR Installation failed: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.VersionInstaller.InstallVersion(Item version) 
at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.VersionInstaller.PasteVersion(XmlNode versionXml, Item target, VersionInstallMode mode, IProcessingContext context, Boolean removeOtherVersions) 
at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry) 
at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.Flush() 
at Sitecore.Install.Framework.SinkDispatcher.Flush() 
at Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush() 
at Sitecore.Install.Framework.EntryBuilder.Flush() 
at Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink) 
at Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, Boolean  registerInstallation, ISource`1 source, IProcessingContext context) 
at Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, ISource`1 source,   IProcessingContext context) 
at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.InstallPackage.InstallPackageForm.AsyncHelper.<Install>b__4() 
at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.InstallPackage.InstallPackageForm.AsyncHelper.CatchExceptions(ThreadStart start)
```

So it seems like a version failed, but the item only has one version in the source instance of Sitecore. I am not sure why this failed.

**Edit**

I have a posted a package with the item in question here:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uzxls6mv68evoce/AAAkbtK8YAXi6QUWdlk28869a?dl=0

**Edit 2**

It has nothing to do with this particular item. I tried removing the item from the package and re-importing and I just get the same error on a different item.

Comment: Please create a package that consists only of the template item in question and its subitems. Upload it somewhere and add a link to your question. Then we'll be able to debug your issue.

Comment: I was able to install that package into a fresh install of Sitecore 7.2 update-6 and received no error. I'm guessing the problem is related to something specific to your setup. Can you install any packages? What about packages with files only (no items)?

Comment: I was able to install the package on Sitecore.NET 7.1 (rev. 140324).. Any additional info from log files? Make sure that master database is selected.

Comment: I do not believe it is that particular item. I removed that item from the package and it just failed on a different item. I tried installing a package with just files and it installed fine.

Comment: Its definitely installing to master.

Comment: I installed your package without problem. So the issue is with your Sitecore instance, not with the package. What version of Sitecore are you using? What customizations have you applied? Installed modules? Configuration changes? Have you recently upgraded from an earlier Sitecore version?

Comment: What is the Sitecore version are you using?

Comment: Sitecore.NET 7.2 (rev. 140526)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this had to do with Indexing. Go figure. The index database and the OnPublishEndAsync were pointing to different databases.

Answer (score 1):

The package appears to be corrupt.

The main zip validates fine, but if you test the `package.zip` embedded in the archive, it reports as corrupt.

[image]

Result

[image]

Comment: That's just WinRAR being funny. It will say that the `package.zip` is corrupt for any package created in Sitecore (as far as my tests show).